# How to add width to a specific column in TOP

Tags: top

I would like to have the nTH (Number of threads column) wider on the top output I have configured.  right now it is truncated a 4 place value (2K+ thread count).  to **28+** I would like it to display all 4 positions of the value.   I have not been able to figure out how to change that column width.  when I try the command to do it with the toggles in Top it was only affecting the USER column.   I assume I am missing something on how to select a different column for the option to affect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a set of columns that the X option affects.   nTH (number of threads) is not one of those columns.  there appears to be no way with Top to affect the width of that column.